# Symbolic optimization - Python or MatLab

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, symbolic-math

I am trying to replicate this exercise from Garicano (2000), that maximizes this equation:
[That is the problem of optimization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr4Bj.png), and I want to get the solutions for z_w and z_m. So that I achieve to arrive to here: [Solutions to Garicano problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pojx.png).

So I have tried in MatLab and Python. But in MatLab I got an issue to resolve the problem, a kind of adaptation from Garicano, I understand that as I do not have numerical values then I cannot use Matlab:

```matlab
%%   Model of firm layers' with knowledge transmission & Trainment
clear all;
clc;

syms z_w z_m z h t w n a1 a2 a3 L

% Here we are using the objective function with the restriction included

F = ((1-exp(-L*z_m))/(h*(1-(1-exp(-L*z_w))))) - (t - a3)*z_m - w*(a3) - (((t - a1).*z_w + w*(a1))/(h*(1-exp(-L*z_w))));


solve(F,z_w)
```

The result from MATLAB is:

```
Warning: Unable to find explicit solution. For options, see help. 
In sym/solve (line 317)
In untitled3 (line 12) 
 
ans =
 
Empty sym: 0-by-1
```

And I have used Python:

```py
from __future__ import division
from simpy import *
from sympy import symbols, exp, diff, solve

### We define the variables and parameters

z_m, z_w, z = symbols('z_m z_w z', positive = True)
L = symbols('lambda')
h, t, w, n, a1, a2, a3, L = symbols('h t w n a1 a2 a3 L', Real = True)
F, C1, m = symbols('F C1 m')

# Defining the function
Objective = ((1-exp(-L*z_m))/(h*(1-(1-exp(-L*z_w)))))-(t - a3)*z_m-w*(a3)-(((t - a1)*z_w + w*(a1))/(h*(1-exp(-L*z_w))))
Objective

C1 = h*n*(1-exp(m-L*z_w))
C1

# Identify the Objective function
Lag = Objective
Lag

#First order conditions

FOC_1 = diff(Lag,z_w)
FOC_2 = diff(Lag,z_m)


Solutions = solve([FOC_1, FOC_2], [z_w, z_m])
```

But it shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9cff7d4c192f> in <module>
----> 1 Solutions = solve([FOC_1, FOC_2], [z_w, z_m])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1094         solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
   1095     else:
-> 1096         solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
   1097 
   1098     #

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in _solve_system(exprs, symbols, **flags)
   1887                     got_s.add(s)
   1888                 if not hit:
-> 1889                     raise NotImplementedError('could not solve %s' % eq2)
   1890             else:
   1891                 result = newresult

NotImplementedError: could not solve h**4*(-1 + h*(-a3 + t)*exp(L*z_m)/L)**3*(-a3 + t)**2*(exp(L*z_m) - 1)*exp(2*L*z_m)/L + h**4*(-1 + h*(-a3 + t)*exp(L*z_m)/L)*(-a3 + t)**2*(a1*w + (-a1 + t)*(L*z_m + log(h*(-a3 + t)/L))/L)*exp(3*L*z_m)/L - h**4*(-1 + h*(-a3 + t)*exp(L*z_m)/L)**2*(-a1 + t)*(-a3 + t)**2*exp(3*L*z_m)/L**2
```

I would really appreciate your help since I do not understand very well how to establish a symbolic optimization problem.

Any feedback would be really helpful.
Thanks.

I have tried to change the program, and use the symbolic functions, although it does not work.

Comment: What does “I thought in Julia but I do not know that program” mean? Did you or did you not try to solve it in Julia? If not, then just delete that sentence. In fact, you’re better off to just show code and error messages for one language, remove mentions of the other languages. What output did you get from the MATLAB code?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. The MATLAB code resulted in this: Warning: Unable to find explicit solution. For options, see help. 
> In sym/solve (line 317)
In untitled3 (line 12) 
 
ans =
 
Empty sym: 0-by-1

Comment: Ok. That means the expression is not in one of the forms that the tool recognizes, or can not be converted to such a form. I’m guessing the Python error “could not solve” means the same thing.

Comment: By the way, with the MATLAB code you are solving `F==0` for `z_w`. If you want to maximize the expression, you might want to solve for the derivative of `F` equal to 0.

Comment: Simplify your equation a bit by hand to remove all the bogus brackets that serve only to obfuscate meaning and then try it in Maxima. Assuming you are looking for its maximum then differentiate once and then solve for z_m or z_w. You might find it easier renaming the unknowns to x and y since Maxima defaults to solving for x. It gets a closed form solution. It's idea of "simplest" looks a little odd to me... However you can only hope to get to z_m = f(z_w) or vice versa for this unless you are very lucky. Possible that the functional forms are chosen to work out that way.